# WHERE NOT IN SQL Performance

Tags: optimization, sql, sql-server, random

```
SELECT TOP 1 l.ID 
FROM Leads l
WHERE 
     l.ID NOT IN (SELECT LeadID FROM LeadFollowups) 
     AND l.ID NOT IN (SELECT LeadID FROM LeadsWorking)
     AND l.ID NOT IN (SELECT LeadID FROM LeadsDead)
     AND l.ID NOT IN (SELECT LeadID FROM LeadHolds)
     AND l.ID >= (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Leads))
ORDER BY l.QualityScore DESC
```

I have a table growing by a 10 to 100 thousand rows a day.  I have several tables to track actions of the current leads that shouldn't be included when grabbing the new lead.  My query is pretty quick now, but as this grows is `NOT IN` the most efficient solution for this? Especially if I get in to the range of ~10 million rows in the Leads table?

Comment: what does `l.ID >= (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Leads))` and why do you need this?

Comment: Before adding the QualityScore calculation, I was just returning a random row with that line.

Comment: so you weren't even checking the rows less than some random ID?

Comment: Is `LeadID` nullable in any of the columns in the various LeadX tables? If so you [should consider `NOT EXISTS`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/73226) or explicitly adding `WHERE LeadID IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is correctly indexed with the ID column from each table as the primary key, then I don't see this query slowing down much as the data grows.

You are worrying prematurely, I think.... but, the purpose of the query is complicated... it is almost as if you are tying to find a random lead to prompt people to look in to 'next'.... where that lead has not been handled in some way yet.

I think you may have better performance with a cursor.... (in a stored procedure?).

Still, even if you have to do the large checks of all the 'handled' leads, you may find it faster to do just the one 'big' subselect instead of multiple smaller ones. you will need to test this on your system to get an idea of the performance.

```
with (
      SELECT LeadID FROM LeadFollowups
    UNION
      SELECT LeadID FROM LeadsWorking
    UNION
      SELECT LeadID FROM LeadsDead
    UNION
      SELECT LeadID FROM LeadHolds
) as handled
select TOP 1 leads.ID
from Leads leads
where leads.ID >= (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Leads))
  and leads.ID not in (select LeadID from handled)
ORDER BY leads.QualityScore DESC
```

I don't like that your query can return zero results when the `RAND()` value is large... and all higher ID's are handled.

As a cursor / procedure, it will process much less data, and, as a consequence, it will likely be faster. The big difference is that it will terminate early (when it has found a valid answer), rather than calculating all the valid answers, and selecting one of them.

It could be something like:

```
declare @leadid as int;
declare @count as int = 0;

declare LEADCURSOR cursor for
select leads.ID
from Leads leads
where leads.ID >= (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Leads))
ORDER BY leads.QualityScore DESC

open LEADIDS

fetch next from LEADIDSinto @leadid
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    select @count = count(*)
    from LeadFollowups, LeadsWorking, LeadsDead, LeadHolds
    where LeadFollowups.leadID = @leadid
      and LeadsWorking.leadID = @leadid
      and LeadsDead.leadID = @leadid
      and LeadHolds.leadID = @leadid

    if (@count = 0)
        BREAK

    fetch next from LEADIDSinto @leadid
end
close LEADIDS
deallocate LEADIDS

if (@count <> 0)
    set @leadid = null

select @leadid
```

Comment: I am skeptical that the cursor processes much less data.  For one thing, it's querying the various anti-join tables zero or more times, possible very many times.

Comment: Perhaps that UNION could be a materialized view.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades - With the `>=` condition on the `RAND()` function, I don't believe that SQLServer can use that as a deterministic predicate as it compiles the SQL Plan. Thus, the query, at best, because of the NOT IN, becomes a index-scan of Leads.ID, with nested-loop index-probe for each sub-table... Thus, *every* LeadID is scanned before it can satisfy the `TOP 1`... With the cursor approach we do the same thing, but start from the 'right place', and terminate early.

Comment: My suspicion/hope (and why I recommend *trying it* ) is that the there will be much fewer cursor loops than nested-loops. This will depend on data distributions, usage patterns, etc.

Comment: There's still the repeated scanning of the anti-tables.  Why not capture the set of disallowed lead IDs once?  I'd probably dump it into a temp table rather than materialize it as Chris suggested, but any approach that avoids re-querying the same data will surely scale better.

Comment: I do see your point about reducing the loops, for sure, I just don't see why it's necessary to loop at all.  Wish I had the exact data to test!

Comment: @JonofAllTrades - I disagree that there are repeated scanns of the anti-tables .... each anti-table will have a single index-probe per loop. (assuming it has the logical index on LeadID)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was using "scans" sloppily.  Repeated *examinations*; in this case, probings - IF those fields are indexed.  They probably are.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  You are exactly correct in the purpose of the function, to pull a random lead to work that is free.

Comment: With the current 800,000 rows in the leads, and an average of 5,000 rows in each of the "anti"-tables, it is running very well. I just wanted to make sure the software wouldn't get killed in the coming months.

Comment: This means very little to me, but if it will satisfy your curiosity: http://i.imgur.com/iwtPhN0.png

Comment: Unions and cursors? I really doubt that either would produce a better query plan. The Union *might*. Maybe.

Comment: "With the >= condition on the RAND() function, I don't believe that SQLServer can use that as a deterministic predicate" this is an incorrect assumption. `RAND` is a runtime constant in SQL Server, it can certainly be evaluated once and used in a seek.

Comment: Yes that's true. If the optimal plan shape would vary due to selectivity then one possible approach would be to store the result of `(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Leads))` in a variable then use  `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get SQL Server to take account of the value.

Answer (score 6):

> My query is pretty quick now, but as this grows is NOT IN the most efficient solution for this?

I expect it would be quicker if you had an indexed `Status` field in the `Leads` table (so that records in the `LeadsDead` table had a corresponding `Status=Dead` in the `Leads` table); and quicker still if `Status` were a clustered index, so that all the leads with a given `Status` were contiguous in the `Leads` table.

Comment: if only we could go back in time and slap the person creating the database structure (in some cases) and tell them the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT:

If you can, you should add a column to your leads table, something like `beingHandled` (boolean/bit) then you could write a query that would set it once for all the records which might take a little bit of time but it only needs to be run once.

After you have done this you can query this table super simple

```
SELECT leads.ID
FROM Leads AS leads
WHERE beingHandled = true
```

Then you just need to keep this table up to date with your {application?}.

Let the application handle picking a random lead from the data set of leads that haven't been handled.  In my opinion, asking a RDBMS to randomly pick a record seems completely wrong, I see that a database was created to organize data and not scramble it.

You also never mention if the record that was returned is going to be added to one of the tables that are mentioned in the where clause, **so you could return the same result twice**.

I assume that your application is handling the part of creating the record in the other tables, so why not let the application also update the `Leads` table `beingHandled` value to `true` as well.

---

---

Can you pick an ID and say anything less than that ID doesn't need to be checked?

I think that you will lose a little bit of performance by running the random function, probably not much, but if you can eliminate all the records older than some date, that would speed up the query by not having to run through so many records in the first place.

so this line of SQL,

```
AND l.ID >= (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Leads))
```

Smells Badly to me

you are saying that you only want to check more recent leads, what if this line of code says

```
l.ID >= ({123455}) -- Translated after code does it's thing
```

and there are only `123456` Records?

---

let's also think about this for a minute,

same line of code in the where statement,

the query comes to a row and checks all the where statements, which means that it is picking a different random ID for every record that it checks, this can't be accurate, and probably isn't what you intend this line of code to do.

**you should look into changing this line of code**

```
AND l.ID >= (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Leads))
```

---